# Troubles with select.list()

Tags: r, tcltk

I was trying to generate a dialog box where a user can select elements to keep, however the item I want to keep is a character but it looks like R is giving them numeric values based on their alphabetical rank. Here's an example (I would prefer the list in the dialog box to be 1:Red, 2:Yellow, 3: Blue instead it's giving me 2, 3, 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tcltk)
library(utils)

x<-c(1,2,5)
y<-c(7,2.2,8)
c<-c("red", "yellow", "blue")

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,c),stringsasfactors=FALSE)

answer<-tk_select.list(df$c, preselect = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
            title = "Select items to keep:")

selected_df<-filter(df, c %in% answer)

selected_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the `data.frame` as

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With this, the output of `selected_df` is

```
selected_df
#  x y   c
#1 1 7 red
```

---

NOTE: `stringsasfactors` is not equal to `stringsAsFactors`. So, the `character` columns remain as `factor` class

```
str(as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,c),stringsasfactors=FALSE) )
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","5": 1 2 3
#$ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "2.2","7","8": 2 1 3
#$ c: Factor w/ 3 levels "blue","red","yellow": 2 3 1
```

Also, `as.data.frame(cbind`, would have unnecessary issues as `cbind` returns a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single `class` i.e. all the columns are converted to `character` class because the values in 'c' are `character`.  When we use `as.data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, it does create `character` class but `numeric` columns should remain numeric